# Random password generator same string

Tags: c, random, passwords

This is my first C program and I wanted to make a random password, but every time I run the program, it generates the same string. (always generates "pkDHTxmMR1...") This is not going to actually be used so the security of rand() doesn't really matter to me. Why would it output the same string every time that I run it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  
//this is a program to generate a random password

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    char randChar;

    int  passwordLength;

    printf("Type in a password Length \n");
    scanf("%d", &passwordLength);

    while(counter < passwordLength)
    {
        //seed random based on time
        srand(time(NULL));
        randChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"[random () % 62];    
        printf("%c", randChar);
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL)); int r = rand(); randChar[r%68]` try this

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This program *does* create passwords that consist of the same character all over, but not the same one every run.

Comment: @EOF I didn't understand your comment, you are completely and absolutely right!

Comment: @EOF I just ran the program and got exactly the same result as the questioner, and I mean **exactly** i.e. I got `pkDHTxm`

Comment: I took out the extra  `srand(time(NULL))`, but still comes out with the same exact string. Happens in ideone as well. @iharob

Comment: @EOF macos x snow leopard, gcc compiler

Comment: How are you executing the program?

Comment: ./a.out, then input length @iharob

Comment: @user3121023 absolutely, I never noticed that the OP used `random()` because of the very weird line `"ABCD..."[index]` which bothers me a lot.

Comment: @EOF see my answer for the real problem

Comment: @EOF I literally did a copy-paste of the code into vi and compiled it with clang (OS X) with no special flags and I got the exact same password as Christopher every time.  Because the problem is that the random number generator he was using was not seeded at all.

Comment: @EOF It occurs to me that a C library might make `srand` and `srandom` aliases as well as `rand` and `random`.  If that were the case, you would see the behaviour you were getting.

Comment: @JeremyP: Yes, that's exactly what happens on Linux, `man srand: [...]The versions of rand() and srand() in the Linux C Library use the  same random number generator as random(3) and srandom(3)[...]`, and importantly, according to my tests, on ideone, contrary to what the OP stated in a comment...

Comment: @EOF Yes!! Just a stupid mistake. Worked on ideone, not on gcc. :-)

Comment: @ChristopherCalmes It's not the compiler, it is the C library.  The functions are not aliased on OS X which is why you got the same password on OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear.  Everybody has got the answer wrong, including me before I tried the questioner's code for myself.

In fact, yes there should be no call to `srand()` in the loop because it will reseed the random number generator on each iteration. However, there should also be no call to `srand()` outside the loop either because the function used to generate actual random numbers is `random()` not `rand()`.  The correct code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    srandom(time(NULL));  // Correct seeding function for random()
    char randChar;

    int  passwordLength;

    printf("Type in a password Length \n");
    scanf("%d", &passwordLength);

    while(counter < passwordLength)
    {
        randChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"[random () % 62];
        printf("%c", randChar);
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\n"); // Stops the output from being on the same line as the prompt
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right, but it's really because everyone assumed that the OP used `rand()` instead of `random()`.

Comment: @iharob I've rolled back your edit because a) it's closer to the original code and b) it almost certainly makes no difference to the program.

Comment: It makes no difference you are right about the rollback, sorry it's just that I can't believe that someone would write such a horrible line of code, I know that it's a little bit stupid but I love programming and I feel that this kind of programmers hurt programming, so ... I will delete this comment once I know you read it.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyP :-) newb mistake I guess.

Comment: @iharob Just 2 semesters of java programming in high school. I'm just starting out.

Comment: Java ... that's why such an idea might occur to you, you have to make your code elegant and beautiful, even if you are starting, I don't really blame you, it's that there are so many online resources with bad style and bad practice, that it's quite easy to run into this kind of thinking, and Java seems to help, I've noticed that many java programmers don't really care to format their code nicely, even though the eclipse thing has the functionality to make it easy.

Comment: @iharob I would have written the code the same way as you, but I don't see anything intrinsically wrong except that it is the equivalent of a "magic number" in the code.

Comment: @iharob how would you have done it? I thought that this way makes it machine independent because it doesn't rely on ascii **edit**: ascii not ancii... midnight in Taiwan)

Comment: What is `ancii`? and I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ChristopherCalmes Look at his edit of my answer (edit 2 in the history) by clicking on the "edited xx minutes ago" link

Comment: @ChristopherCalmes Although note that there is a bug in his answer in that he forgets that `sizeof(characters)` is one too big due to the terminating `\0`

Comment: Right, so no magic numbers and use a const. The formatting is bad because....nano. @iharob Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop takes less than a second to run.

Therefore, `time(NULL)` always returns the same value, so your random numbers all have the same seed.

Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The standard:

> The `srand` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of
>   pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand`. If
>   `srand` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of
>   pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.

It is very likely that the `time_t` on your system is based on seconds or something like that. But the execution time between `srand()` calls is far far less than one second, so you keep feeding it the same seed value.

Always just call `srand()` once in your whole program.